# How to get the full version number of a browser with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, versioning, user-agent

In my Chrome's settings, it's showing the full version numbers: `114.0.5735.6` (Major, minor, patches, build)

[image: Chrome's settings showing all version numbers]

I tried using `window.navigator.userAgent` and another website like https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ but they just return the major & minor numbers as `114.0`.

#### Questions:

1. Is there a way to get the full version numbers with JavaScript?
2. Is it possible to achieve without using an external library?
3. What is the reason behind not being able to get the full browser version easily?

Comment: _"Is there a way to get the full version numbers with JavaScript?"_ No. _"Is it possible to achieve without using an external library?"_ No. _"What is the reason behind not being able to get the full browser version easily?"_ I guess, privacy and security.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Chrome version 101 (completed at version 110), Chrome has begin to do user-agent reduction to ensure it is harder to perform browser fingerprinting now: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/user-agent-reduction-android-model-and-version/ - In fact, other browsers also already send less info in their User Agent.

This is part of the Privacy Sandbox initiative by Google to ensure a better privacy of our users: https://privacysandbox.com/

For more information specifically about the User Agent reduction: https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/user-agent/